# Double integral - Volume

Tags: integration, volume

I find it very difficult to solve this problem. I need help setting the integral up. I know that the first one is cone and the third one is paraboloid, but I can't define the limits.
Some explanation would be nice, too. Thanks in advance.

Find the volume of the solid between the surfaces, using double integral

$z^2=x^2+y^2,\\z\geq 0\\2-z=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Hello and welcome to M.SE. Please provide your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Set this up in cylindrical coordinates. The two surfaces intersect when $z^2=2-z$, so you can figure out the limits on $r$ from this.

Comment: What is the connection between 
**z** and **r**? 
$\\x=rcosa,$
$y=rsina,$
$z=z,$
$|Y|=r$

and $0\leq\ r\leq1$ 
because **z1= 1** and **z2=-2** but **z** is positive so its 1? 


Is this the right direction? I really do not understand this, so I'm only guessing :/

Comment: Right. The surfaces intersect when $z=1$. Thus, $0\le r\le 1$. For each fixed $r$, $z$ goes from what to what? Study some examples done in cylindrical coordinates!!

Comment: I've used cylindrical coordinates in triple integrals only.
I spent a lot of time researching and brainstorming, trying to figure this out. If I was able to understand it and solve it, I wouldn't ask for help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You want a triple integral. Integrate $\iiint_V 1 dV$.

Comment: @user3476022 Ted is trying to help you. Don't be rude.

Comment: That wasn't meant to be rude, sorry. 
I have to solve the problem using double integral :( I know how to do it with tripple

Comment: Well, if you know how to do it with triple, then you know how to do it with double. Just integrate the $z$-height for each point to get the volume. That's what the innermost ($\int dz$) integral gives you in triple. Obviously, use polar coordinates.  ... And you should give your effort and what you're trying to do and save us the hassle of trying to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see what I've done so far? Is this the right way?

$z^2=x^2+y^2,\\z\geq 0\\2-z=x^2+y^2$

$z^2+z-2=0\\z=1 => x^2+y^2 = 1$

$x=rcosa\\y=rsina\\|Y|=r$

$0\le r\le 1\\0\le a\le2\pi$

$V=\int\int f1(x,y)-f2(x,y)dxdy$

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r\\2-x^2-y^2 = 2-r^2=> V=\int_0^{2\pi}da\int_0^1 (2-r^2-r)dr$